# hiding a span in mootools

Tags: mootools, javascript-framework, show-hide

i'va simple code in mootools which shows hides a span tag..but by default, it sows the text which i want to be shown only upon clicking a show button..
can anyone tell me how to hide a span tag in mootools?

```
Element.implement({
fancyShow: function(){this.fade('in');},fancyHide: function() {this.fade('out');}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$$("span").setStyle("display", "none");
```

or if you want to have it work with the style consistent with fade, which tweens opacity:

```
$$("span").setOpacity(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a mootools user but I'm pretty sure it should be done with css

```
.selector span {display: none;}
```

Comment: i used it..but it never display the span even when slicked on show..think css overriding :(